# Jackson List<E> json serialization

Tags: java, json, serialization, jersey, jackson

Hi, im creating a jersey 2.0+ rest web service. I was using 1.7 and now im trying to migrate it to 2.0.

I have 2 classes with E objects for handle responses:

```
public class JsonMessageSingle<E> {

private int status;
private String message;
private E data; // for single objects
```

}

And one that uses:

```
private List<E> data; // for list of objects
```

My responses are all in this format:

```
@GET
@Produces("application/json")
public JsonMessageList<User> getUser() {
    List<User> list = new UserDao<User>().findAll();

    return new JsonMessageList<User>(list); //constructor create status and message basesd on object passed (if null == "error")
}
```

Using jersey 1.7 everything was ok on the response, but now i got:

```
HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error
```

And no exception/error on the console. It cant serialize the List>E<, all other objects are serialized correctly. Can someone help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are the only generic class not serialised to JSON or all the others as well? It would be really to easy diagnose the problem if you can get the exception details.

Comment: Its just the E. If i change return to JsonMessageList (instead of JsonMessageList<User>) it serializes, but the user list become just the java id of the object (user@ihdh342bd, that java id, not the user). Im using Tomcat with jersey, theres no error`s in the console, and none in the log either. Thank your for your response.

Answer (score 0):

Find out it was my mistake. Even if you have jackson as dependences (as sugested by jersey itself) you have to configure jersey.media to use jackson as default parser.


**Using maven, update your pom.xml with:**

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
   <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
   <version>2.10.1</version>
</dependency>
```

**instead of:**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
   <version>2.10.1</version>
</dependency>
```